# find with :include - testing controllers with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

i have some action in my rails application

```
  def show
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:id], :include => [:answers, :comments])
    @answers = @issue.answers
    @comments = @issue.comments

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @issue }
    end
  end
```

and rspec test

```
  def mock_issue(stubs={})
    @mock_issue ||= mock_model(Issue, stubs)
  end


  describe "GET show" do
    it "assigns the requested issue as @issue" do
      @issue = mock_issue
      @answers = mock("answers")
      @comments = mock("comments")

      Issue.stub(:find).with("37").and_return(@issue)
      @issue.stub(:answers).and_return([@answers])
      @issue.stub(:comments).and_return([@comments])

      get :show, :id => "37"
      assigns[:issue].should equal(@issue)
    end
  end
```

on attempt to run following test i see error

```
NoMethodError in 'IssuesController GET show assigns the requested issue as @issue'
undefined method `find' for #<Class:0x105dc4a50>
```

but without **:include => [:answers, :comments]** it works fine. Could you tell me please - is there any way to stub :include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ooh, i can answer my question :)

```
 Issue.stub(:find).with("37", :include => [:answers, :comments]).and_return(@issue)
```